# eb create ERROR: LargeZipFile :: Files count would require ZIP64 extensions

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but when I do an eb create for my node js express app I get this error.

```
$ eb create app-test 
Creating application version archive "app-170215_091947".
ERROR: LargeZipFile :: Files count would require ZIP64 extensions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like that the size of your code base is too big for eb-cli/python's [zipfile library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) to handle.

The limit seems to be 4GB:

> exception zipfile.LargeZipFile The error raised when a ZIP file would
>   require ZIP64 functionality but that has not been enabled.

Can you do a ls -l to check the size of your current code base?

Comment: I'm confused. @Yueyang How does running ls -l help?

Answer (score 1):

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(
        zip_file, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True) as myzip:
    myzip.write(os.path.join(SAVE_PATH, sql))
```

“allowZip64=True” should be used.